# ssh pem file, password and fabric script

Tags: ssh, ubuntu-14.04, fabric, pem

I have a fabric script that I use to do some works on several different AWS servers. Recently I moved all my development work on a Ubuntu 14 LTS server on virtualbox and every time I want to use my script ssh ask me the password. To avoid the problem I must run the following commands for every terminal opened

```
$ ssh-add PEM_FILE
$ ssh-agent /bin/bash
```

On macosx I never had to run the ssh-agent, but I just added the pem file with ssh-add.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Add the script to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
if [ "x$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" = "x" ]; then
    eval `ssh-agent`
    ssh-add PEM_FILE
fi
```

To make sure your shells have the agent running. Ubuntu desktops usually runs also agents. But the above method is probably the easiest.